# How can I move a collection into another collection in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

This seems like a simple enough thing to do, but I've been trying for a bit and can't seem to find out how to do it. Basically I already have a bunch of collections, and I simply want to move one of them into another. For example, if I have the collections:

> - Fruits
> - Vegetables
> - Apples

I want to move "Apples" into "Fruits," like so:

> - Fruits
>
>   - Apples
> - Vegetables

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Drag and drop doesn't work; and nothing in the right-click menu or the (seemingly useless) "Organize" menu hints at how to do this.

**Note: I do not want to *create* a new collection inside of an existing one. I want to *move* an already-created collection into another existing one.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. The product name was changed and it no longer handle collections. The changes are complex. Better to ask a new question than update this one.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out shortly after posting; it turns out the "Organize" menu isn't *useless*, just unintuitive. To add a collection to another one, choose "Organize" from the right-click menu and then check the collection(s) you want to add it to. If you don't want it to appear as one of the "root" collections, uncheck the "My Collections" item.

I suppose this is actually a better way of doing this than I was thinking, since it allows you to add a collection to as many others as you'd like.